# how to return values from a function in a controller's scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I was trying to create a map and populate it with markers in angular and it went well. Now I trying to give latitude and longitude to the center of $cope.map returned from a function.  How can I do so? function currently returns 'Undefined' why is that?? is there a better way to do so?? I am stuck since very long  and I am new to angular. Can you help? please? below is my code.

```js
var appa = angular.module('appa',['firebase','uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
appa.controller('mainCtrl', function($firebaseObject,$scope) {

          $scope.coords = function(){
            var ref =  firebase.database().ref();
            var latArray = [];
            var lngArray = [];
            var cenlat;
            var cenlng;
              var marker = [];
            ref.once("value")
            .then(function(snapshot)
            {

            snapshot.forEach(function(child){
              latArray.push(child.child("Lat").val());
              lngArray.push(child.child("Long").val());
              var mark = {
              id: child.child("Id").val(),
              coords: {
              latitude: child.child("Lat").val(),
              longitude: child.child("Long").val()
              },
              options: { title: child.child("Alt").val() }
              };
              marker.push(mark);
            });

               cenlat = (Math.max.apply(Math,latArray)+Math.min.apply(Math,latArray)/2);
               cenlng = (Math.max.apply(Math,lngArray)+Math.min.apply(Math,lngArray)/2);

            });
            $scope.map.moo = cenlat;
          };
          $scope.map = {
            moo: "0",
            center:
            {
                    latitude: $scope.map.moo, longitude: 4 },
             zoom: 2
                  };
                  $scope.coords();


   });
```

Comment: may I suggest you don't inject $scope and use the controllerAs Syntax in your code, you can then just set it on this. Also take a look at typescript with angular, in my option doing javascript without types is troublesome in the long run..

Comment: After looking at your code, it look like the ref.once is returning a promise. could it be your promise has not resolved yet, and when you set cenLat there is nothing in there yet. I would move all off that logic code to a service and have it return a promise that you result.. I am betting it is an issue with your promise not being resolved. A timing issue

Comment: put a breakpoint on the where you populate the latArray and one on the code where you set centLat, you might see you are reaching the centLat code before the other code is done..

Comment: No! I put a break and found that all of my foreach loop was running in complete and after that i am executing cenlat for longitute average. and I have added what @kidwon told me and reposted here. please have a look. if you can tell me, where to rightly place moo. as it is saying moo is undeined in $scope.map.center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to async closure world of js :)

```
return ref.once("value")
```

and hadle it where you need

```
$scope.map = {};
// invoke
$scope.coords().then(function(snapshot){
  // ...
  $scope.map.moo = cenlat;
});
```

or

give it a callback parameter

```
$scope.coords = function(callback){
  ref.once("value").then(callback);
}


$scope.map = {
  // ...
};
// invoke
$scope.coords(function(snapshot){
  // ...
  $scope.map.moo = cenlat;
});
```

or actually your code:

```
$scope.map = {};
$scope.coords = function(){
  ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    // ...
    $scope.map.moo = cenlat;
  }
}
```

**To your last question**

```
$scope.coords = function(){
     ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        // ...
        $scope.map.center.latitude = cenlat;
     }
 }

$scope.map = {
    center: {
        longitude: 4
    },
    zoom: 2
};

$scope.coords()
```

Comment: hi! @kidwon can you please put that in my code if possible. It will be further clear for me then please

Comment: @nemoasad does it make sence now?

Comment: I am so sorry to say. It does a  bit more than previous version. I am really new here and it is taking time. I amtrying to get it. :/ i hope it solves

Comment: @nemoasad Just assign the result to the map not returning it. If I understood correctly you want `cenlat` into the `$scope.map`, right?

Comment: what is this 'moo'  exactly??  you are saying that i should not return value but bind it to $scope.map.somevariable? right?

Comment: @nemoasad `moo` is just an example key you can named it  `$scope.map.cenlat = cenlat;` or whatever you want

Comment: okay let me try it. thanks much @kidwon. i will reply back my status thanks

Comment: I edited the code as u said but please tell me how to use the 'moo' in $scope.map.center. currently it is saying moo is undefined

Comment: which part precisely?

Comment: @nemoasad  You can't address object references at the time you are creating it. It is not yet created. Also you have to address each reference with the proper tree keys.

Comment: I have already told the problem i need to get my returned values in latitutde and longitude. how to get them? i have now added the proper reference keys(tree) please tell me in action. what can I do? please

Comment: thanks @kidwon  your time really helped me in learning. I was actually down after working whole day. Thanks much. i reached some where near after this. I hope to get it done soon. :)

Comment: @nemoasad Look the code example I gave you it is all there. Set the longitude the same way I show it to you with the latitude :)